# I had ripe bananas so I peeled them, put them in Rubbermaid cont and in the fridge. Are they still ok to use?

Tags: bananas

They are darkish in color but not black. Still ok for bread?

Comment: How long did you leave them in the fridge?

Answer (score -1):

The fridge is  the best method to store ripe bananas, and should be fine for 5 to 7 days. Refrigeration will make the skin of the banana black, but the flesh will remain unharmed.